# Selection of only one user from list

Tags: powershell

I have this script that I need to use to retrieve the data of a particular user "ADTuser"  from a list of servers the script works well, but the output file with my user add also other users' detail that is not needed for my final output how can I filter it to only the user that I need.

```
get-content C:\servers.txt | foreach-object { 
    $Comp = $_ 
    if (test-connection -computername $Comp -count 1 -quiet) { 
        ([ADSI]"WinNT://$comp").Children | ?{$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | %{ 
            $groups = $_.Groups() | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)} 
            $_ | Select @{n='Computername';e={$comp}}, 
            @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}}, 
            @{n='Memberof';e={$groups -join ';'}},
            @{n='status'; e={if($groups -like "*Administrators*"){$true} else{$false}}}
        }  
    } Else {Write-Warning "Server '$Comp' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"} 
} | Out-File -FilePath C:\users.txt
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking to return only if the `UserName` is `ADTuser`, right?

Comment: yes correct if one of the users is ADTuser and export only his details

Comment: Are you using this because `Get-LocalUser` and `Get-LocalMember` are not available on your computers ?

Comment: I tried but I fail unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an easier way of doing what you're looking for, [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) and [`Get-CimAssociatedInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-cimassociatedinstance?view=powershell-7.2) have been around since PowerShell 3:

```
Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $computer = $_
    try {
        $query = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='ADTuser'" -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop
        foreach($object in $query) {
            $membership = Get-CimAssociatedInstance -InputObject $object -ResultClassName Win32_Group -ComputerName $_

            [pscustomobject]@{
                Computername = $_
                UserName     = $object.Name
                Memberof     = $membership.Name -join ';'
                Status       = $membership.Name -contains 'Administrators'
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Server '$computer' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If that doesn't work for you, your code would require a simple modification on your first filtering statement:

```
Where-Object { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.Name.Value -eq 'ADTuser' }
```

It's important to note that `Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet` is not a relevant test for this script, this command is testing for ICMP response and `adsi` over `WinNT` [**requires RPC connectivity as well SMB**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/22f5a999-70b3-443c-8334-39a18035dddb/powershell-active-directory-adsi?forum=winserverpowershell).

Putting it all together with minor improvements the script would look like this:

```
Get-Content C:\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Server '$_' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"
        return
    }
    
    $computer = $_
    ([adsi]"WinNT://$_").Children.ForEach{ 
        if($_.SchemaClassName -ne 'user' -and $_.Name.Value -ne 'ADTuser') {
            return
        }
        
        $groups = $_.Groups().ForEach([adsi]).Name
        
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Computername = $computer
            UserName     = $_.Name.Value
            Memberof     = $groups -join ';'
            Status       = $groups -contains 'Administrators'
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thanks for your adjustment just one question. how can I adapt the script to run on multiple server if I run it on a really short list 1 /2  the script work fine but if is  a long list 20 the script doesn't work

Comment: @ElyasKarim please ask a new question explaining what is not working and adding if there are any errors, also in the question provide which one of this 2 snippets you're using (I would recommend you to use the first one)

Comment: hello @Santiago Squarzon thanks for your fast reply I use the second snippets it provide me a better result the first one generate an output file with the pscustomobject status always false. the problem that I experiencing is basically a lot of server are reported as Unreachable hence Could not fetch data, while if I try to manually connect a lot of them are online. did you have any suggestion to give me thanks again for your time

Comment: @ElyasKarim the second snippet looks good to me, if it's not working for some hosts it's either permissions or a network issue. the first snippet was clearly wrong (my bad) I've updated it

Comment: yeah I look over and over both snippet and are perfect. I will exclude the network issue because I test the network connect before, during and after and was ok I believe that is more likely a permissions issue. did you think that add a line $cred = get-credential can fix the problem

Comment: @ElyasKarim `test-connection` is not a reliable source of information to tell you if you can connect to a remote host, `adsi` with `WinNT` will connect using RPC protocol and CIM will connect using WinRM protocol, you should test connect over those ports before attempting to connect instead of ICMP. Aside from that your user has to be an administrator over the remote hosts.

Comment: I was testing the code from the first snippet and I keep getting the error ws-management could not connect I check on my server and all the process relate winrm are active and running what else can be?